# $a_1+a_2+…+a_n=2008$ where all $a_i$ are positive integers. If $A_k = a_1 a_2 … a_k$ , what is the largest possible value of $A_1+A_2+…+A_n$?

Tags: combinatorics

The sum of a set of positive integers = $2008$.

$a_1+a_2+…+a_n=2008$ where all $a_i$ are positive integers.

If $A_k=a_1 a_2 … a_k$ , what is the largest possible value of $A_1+A_2+…+A_n$ ?

Comment: [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: So there can be duplicates?

Comment: Yes, duplicates are allowed

Comment: What have you looked at?  If you drop the condition that the $\{a_i\}$ are all integral then I expect the maximum for a fixed $n$ is realized when all of them are equal, and that if if you maximize over $n$ you want $n\approx \frac {2008}e$ so something like $n=739$.  Not clear to me how to cope with integrality. I mean, you could take $530$ threes and $209$ twos but I have no idea if that is optimal.

Comment: Having not put much thought into it yet, an observation I make is that $A_1+A_2+\dots+A_n = a_1(1+a_2(1+a_3(1+a_4(\dots (1+a_n))\dots)$.  This might or might not be a helpful observation

Comment: this can be easily programmed, would it help?

Comment: $n$ can be any value

Comment: Programming may help. My thinking so far has been on these lines: Just set all $a_n$ to the same value, starting with, say $a_1 = a2 = a_3 = 2$, and then 3, 4, etc. Then the question is as we increase this value and calculate the  sum of powers of 2, 3,4, etc, will there be an inflection point somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the $a_i$ must come in weakly decreasing order.

If $a_1+\dots+a_n=2008$ with $a_1$ an even number bigger than $2$, then consider $$(a_1/2)+2+a_2+\dots+a_n+1+\dots+1=2008.$$
If $a_1+\dots+a_n=2008$ with $a_1$ odd and at least $5$, say $a_1=2k+1$, consider 
$$
(a_1-2)+2+a_2\dots+a_n=2008
$$
(Clearly $a_1=1$ cannot be maximal). 
Once you have figured out $a_1$, apply the same argument to $a_2$, $a_3$, etc.
(edit: at each step above, replace $j$ trailing copies of $1$ by the integer $j$; that is, instead of using $2006+1+1$, use $2006+2$. Doing this does not change the result).

This shows that each $a_i$ must be $3$ or $2$. Simplifying the terms $A_1+\dots+A_n$ is now just adding terms of a 2 geometric series. Finally, if there are $k$ $3s$ then there are $\frac{2008-3k}{2}$ $2s$; thus we want to maximize 
$$
\frac{3(3^k-1)}{2}+\frac{3(3^k-1)}{2}\cdot2\cdot\left(2^\frac{2008-3k}{2}-1\right)
$$
From Wolframalpha this gives $668$ copies of $3$ and $2$ copies of $2$ for an answer of roughly $3\times 10^{319}$